# Why is my LibreOffice so slow?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

Every time I start LibreOffice, I have to wait 3 minutes before I'm able to start working (screen is grey). Why? Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Regrets
Malte

Comment: What are your computer specifications?

Comment: What specific programm are you using? Impress, Writer or Calc?

Comment: 2,1 Ghz DualCore E4600, 2GB Ram, GeForce 4900GTX, i dont think its cause of my hardware

Comment: Im using Writer

Comment: Does this happen on ubuntu 12.04? Did you upgrade from a previous release?

Comment: Yes, only with ubuntu 12.04. With 11.10 i don't have this problem.

Comment: oh sry, no i didnt upgraded it.

Comment: Does this happen with every document? What happens if you execute `libreoffice --writer`? Any useful output in the terminal?

Comment: yes it happened with every document, and the terminal puts nothing out. :(

Comment: Try turning off java environment if it is enabled - tools -options - java

Answer (score 6):

How you can see [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39659) LibreOffice won't work well with ALL Java versions. The 1.6.0_21 seems to be the best java to use with LibreOffice. The 1.6.0_20 & 1.6.0_22 seem to be in a fairly good 2nd place place. The 1.6.0_24 was really bad and the 1.6.0_26 was even worse apparently.

To install 1.6.0_21 You should first purge every other Java versions from your system (icedtea, open, ecc. all included). 
Unfortunately, it seems near impossible to find compiled packages for precise, so you'll have to consider to build it from source (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sun-java6/6.21-1ubuntu1).

Otherwise, you could disable java plugin for LO, from Tools menu, then Options, Java, uncheck the box.

Last alternative, install other versions of java (such as the last Oracle 1.7) and select it in the list, to see if the problem solves.

Comment: Thanks a lot +1. I disabled Java and it works perfectly now.

Comment: definitely a speed improvement when disabling Java completely in LO

Answer (score 4):

This past week, LO slowed considerably for me, no matter what document. Don't know if it was a change in Java, but LO became unusable in terms of entering numbers in Calc or even typing in Writer.

This is under 14.04 64-bit w/ 8GB of RAM. 
LO Version: 4.2.7.2, Build ID: 420m0(Build:2)

As mentioned above, turning off use of the Java runtime environment: Tools>Options>Advanced within LO, and restarting LO seems to have solved the problem, both for Calc and for Writer.

Comment: no one seems to be answering this question... but it seems to be getting more prevalent. I am seeing a bunch of people asking the same thing. I am having the same thing. But there's no answer. I'm not inexperienced and my laptop is not under load. LibreOffice is doing something weird.

Comment: This solution worked for me!