# LibreOffice slow on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

My PC conf is:
Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5250 @ 1.50GHz × 2 wi 2Gb RAM

I am using LibreOffice 4.2.7.2

My libreoffice is extremely low, even when workin on empty documents. It may take 10 seconds to open the tools dropdown menu.

I tried several tricks published on this forum such as disabling the Java runtime environment ([Why is my LibreOffice so slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153984/why-is-my-libreoffice-so-slow)) and on other websites, i.e. increasing the memory cache (https://www.organicweb.com.au/17237/general-technology/libre-office-slow/).

BTW: my PC has dual-boot and LibreOffice is working fine on windows vista.

Update on info requested by @Wilf

1) I am on a 32bit machine

2) Output of free -m in a situation of normal working day. Everything is running smoothly, expecto LibreOffice:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:          2014       1692        322         29        119        538
  -/+ buffers/cache:       1034        980
  Swap:         2219          0       2219
```

3) Screenshot of my [advanced options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGm4b.png)

Update to the comment by @Muzaffar

Your solution solved my problem, thanks! You should turn your comment into an answer.

UPDATE AFTER FEW HOURS OF TEST: in order to have libreoffice run smoothly I continuously have to delete the recent file history. It's frustrating. Since I work a lot on network files, I suspect that this might be the issue. Will post updates.

UPDATE AFTER THE COMMENT BY @lepe: 
My LibreOffice version is now 4.2.8.2 and the problem is still the same. I am positive that if I have some files accessed by VPN over the network in the recent files the application is more severely slowed down, but I have no idea on the reason. I just delete the recnt files every day (or more than once a day).

Comment: Is Libre Office the only software being so slow? What about other ones?

Comment: Yes, LibreOffice is the only one being so slow. I don't use many GUI applications, but all of them work fine: among them firefox,  Adobe reader, Evince, gedit, and RStudio. All of them work smoothly.

Comment: Maybe clearing recent history of documents will help.

Comment: Are you using [32 or 64bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os), and what is the output of `free -m` *(with Libreoffice open and other programs you normally have running)*, and could you add a screenshot of the [Advanced options menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wDMFa.png)?

Comment: Clearing the recent history did fix it too in my case. Why is that related?

Comment: Disable java.. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153984/why-is-my-libreoffice-so-slow

Comment: Thank for the suggestion @Mcb. I disabled Java (Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Deselect the "Use a Java runtime environment" checkbox). I have to admit that I observed a slight improvement, but I wouldn't say the problem is solved.

Comment: You might find [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Using_Remote_Files) useful.